# Causal expansion of EM fields

Tags: electromagnetism, causality, time-evolution, pair-production

When an electron and positron are created at the same time and location, is it correct to say that the electromagnetic field due to the two particles is zero when $r>ct$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The creation of the electron and positron is an electric dipole, and as they separate the dipole moment increases. So (to lowest order) this produces standard dipole radiation which travels outward at c.

[image: Dipole radiation movie from LMU in Munich]

Comment: Really nice diagram

Comment: Thanks! It is from LMU in Munich. They have a lot of great animations about dipole radiation https://www.en.didaktik.physik.uni-muenchen.de/multimedia/dipolstrahlung/index.html

Comment: It is no longer an electric dipole as they separate.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin that is why I said “to lowest order”.

Comment: The question wasn't about "lowest order".

Comment: @JerroldFranklin actually, it is about the lowest order. All the OP wants to know is if it is zero for $r>ct$. The higher order harmonics are irrelevant for that

Comment: You have to show that all the harmonics are zero for t>c.

Comment: @Jerrold Franklin: It is, though. If you don't "feel" it is, just make $r$ 10x larger, and the dipole separation speed slower.

Comment: "It is, though. If you don't "feel" it is, just make r 10x larger, and the dipole separation speed slower."  What does that mean?

Comment: @JerroldFranklin if you or the OP wish such a proof then you are both free to post such a question. Btw, t>c doesn’t make any sense. The units are wrong and if you mean what I think you mean the sign is backwards

Comment: @The_Sympathizer exactly. And since we are interested only in the leading edge that is when the separation is arbitrarily small and the lowest order dipole approximation is arbitrarily good anyway. So at any finite scale, we are interested in an arbitrarily smaller scale dipole separation. The lowest order approximation is therefore good to arbitrary precision for what this question is asking.

Comment: t>c was a misprint, sorry.  I'm not sure what the picture represents.  My understanding is that all odd multipoles contribute inside the circle.  The electric dipole would only dominate near the edge of the circle.
All the multipoles must vanish for r>ct.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin said “The electric dipole would only dominate near the edge of the circle”. Yes. As I said, the leading edge is the thing of interest for this question

Comment: It is not.  The important region is r>ct where all multipoles must vanish.

Comment: That is trivial. For r>ct the source is an exact dipole with dipole moment 0